# Changing Two Variables in an Integral using Jacobian Determinants

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, jacobian

[image: Questions]

This is a question in my lecture notes:

[image: Answer]

And this is the answer the lecture notes give, I understand the process of the Jacobian determinant being taken but I don't understand why we do $\frac{1}{|J|}$ for the calclulation. Would anyone mind explaining how this substitution is done? Thanks.

Comment: What textbook are you using? The Jacobian should be covered in a section in one of the chapters on multivariable calculus.

Comment: These are my lecture notes from university. Everything is explained well, I understand what the Jacobian is and I understand why we use the Jacobian in this situation. But I don't understand why we use $\frac{∂(x,y)}{∂(ξ,η}$ rather than $\frac{∂(ξ,η)}{∂(x,y}$ which is what we originally calculated.

Comment: $d\zeta = \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x}dx +\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial y}dy$ and you're trying to find it in terms of dx and dy.. so it must be the inverse.

Comment: @King Tha Jacobian must be expressed in terms of derivatives with respect to the new variables. The matrix that was initially presented was the inverse of the Jacobian.